# Python print in embedded python wont display anything to cmd

Tags: python, printing

I have an application that launches a python script with parameters.
When the script runs i print some info on the cmd.
The funny thing is that i can't see anything from the print function on the cmd.

If i redirect sys.stdout to a file i get what i want to print which is strange.

I'm using python 2.6.4.

Anyone encountered something similar?

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Maybe it is obvious but, does your script work in foreground and has tty atached? do you flush the stream?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using cmd.exe on windows? If so, there was or still is known problems trying to print to it using python. I believe the issue is a UTF-8 encoding problem. I have heard the following batch file will fix this issue (never tested).

```
set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
cmd /u /k chcp 65001
set PYTHONIOENCODING=
exit
```

Also its worth checking that your output is actually being flushed, try adding the following:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Hi i've tried with sys.stdout.flush() but that seems not to work (maybe the stream is redirected somewhere, but here is a lot of code so I have to look very deep). The batch file did not seem to work either. I'm stuck with redirecting the stream to a log file.

Comment: It sounds like you are using some kind of third party framework. Have you tried writing a single test file and running that independent of any third party code?